# Does the "1" under multiplicative identity represent a scalar or a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

LADR by Axler states the following conditions for a given set to be a vector space -
[image]

For the additive identity property, 0 is used as a symbol to represent the additive identity. Is "1" being used as a symbol to represent the multiplicative identity? If not, does "1" represent a scalar or a vector (i.e., is $1\in \mathbb{R}$ or is $1\in \text{V}$)?

Comment: $1$ is a scalar.  $0$ might be either a vector or a scalar.  Personally, I find it useful to distinguish the notation, as $\vec 0$ vs $0$, but this is not done universally.  It's a bit confusing to write, e.g.,  "$0v=0$ for all $v\in V$" when what one means is $0\vec v=\vec 0$ for all $\vec v \in V$".

Comment: Multiplication in a vector space is always between a scalar and a vector. More importantly there is no vector called $1$ that comes with a vector spaces. You will eventually cover an identity operator $I$ such that $Iv=v$ for all vectors $v$ but it will be represented by a matrix, not a column vector or scalar.

Comment: You could similarly object to the "distributive properties" part where the symbol $+$ is used both for addition of vectors and for addition of scalars.

Answer (score 2):

In Definition 1.18 Axlers writes

> A *scalar multiplication* on a set $V$ is a function that assigns an element $\lambda v$ to each $\lambda \in F$ and each $v \in V$.

Since we only have two operations on $V$  (additon and scalar multiplication), the only possible interpretation of the expression $1v$ is that

- $1$ is an element of $F$ (in fact the neutral element with respect to multiplication in $F$)
- $v$ is an element of $V$
- $1v$ denotes scalar multiplication of $1$ and $v$.

Also note that Axler explains the motivation for the definition of a vector space before Definition 1.18 and explicitly says

> Scalar multiplication by $1$ acts as expected.